# Spring Cloud Data Flow install on Cloud Foundry fails

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I followed the instructions here http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/getting-started-deploying-spring-cloud-dataflow.html (which seems down currently), but my installation fails when trying to push the admin app.

```
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-04-05T16:39:48.55-0500 [APP/0]      ERR Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'streamController' defined in file [/home/vcap/app/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/admin/controller/StreamController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.module.deployer.ModuleDeployer]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.module.deployer.ModuleDeployer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=processModuleDeployer)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.module.deployer.ModuleDeployer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=processModuleDeployer)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not many details in the attached logs. Could you perhaps attach the entire stacktrace as gist or by other means?

Also, are you:

- pushing the M1 release or the SNAPSHOT build of `dataflow-server`?
- running `dataflow-server` on PCF or PWS?

The usual suspects are around the env-var's required by the `dataflow-server` running on Cloud Foundry; perhaps you could double check the following property values for correctness.

```
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_API_ENDPOINT <API_ENDPOINT>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_ORGANIZATION <ORG>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE <SPACE>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN <DOMAIN>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_SERVICES <REDIS_INSTANCE_NAME>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_USERNAME <USER>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_PASSWORD <PASSWORD>
cf set-env <DATAFLOW_SERVER_APP_NAME> CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION true
```

The discussion in [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/issues/60) thread could be useful, too.

As for the docs, we are currently in the process of migrating to a new data center - see/follow [here](https://twitter.com/springops/status/717418890666479616) for more details. This will be restored very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on Micro-PCF and PWS, it worked for me.
I followed instructions given on the link below. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#overview

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.